# Why does Skype 4.3 look so outdated (old) in Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)?

Tags: 14.04, skype

I installed Skype using the guide found on the Ubuntu documentation:

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype)

Instead of getting the usual GUI I was used to see on Windows, I get this:

[image: Skype on Ubuntu 14.04]

with **actually no ads or anything. It looks like a Windows XP-type of GUI.**

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Because it is. It's Skype 4.3. The latest is something like 6.4 or 7. You'll see some Ubuntu apps that look like they were ported directly from Windows 2000 or XP.

Comment: Your image is for Windows 8, not Ubuntu, by the way.

Comment: So for Linux there is no updated version? Not even the one you can download from their website? (I was trying to avoid downloading and installing packages manually).

Comment: The link for the image was my example of what I was expecting. The Ubuntu image is a photo I wanted to upload and couldn't (lack of reputation)

Comment: Upload to Imgur and edit the link into your question. I'll put it as an embedded image.

Comment: Nope, not even with addds.

Comment: 4.3 is the latest version of Skype that is currently offered on the Skype website for Ubuntu and other Linux distributions. As the guide said **Skype is not a software package maintained by the Linux community**. Please turn to the manufacturer if you have any feedback or complaints about the status of the software in Linux.

Comment: ... and the 3rd party owned is Microsoft. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What have I done wrong?

Nothing.

Skype is not maintained by Ubuntu or even anyone in the Linux community. Skype is currently owned by Microsoft and they do not care about other operating systems than their own unless someone pays them to care.

Microsoft bought Skype 10th of May 2011, that is probably when it stopped getting new versions and the current release kept that version.

Comment: @qoelet: It might actually be a good thing to be stuck with a backward 4.3.x version of Skype. The up-to-date version in Windows has publicity, an unwieldy GUI  and, I surmise, social network hooks that could be an real annoyance. I dread to see the day when Skype for Linux will be "updated". Don't you know what "upgrade" has recently come to mean in the MS world ?